# name conflict between popbox.css and bootstrap.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed that there is a problem if both popbox.css and bootstrap.css are used. Does anybody know a solution for that? 
Here is a fiddle from somebody to show how popbox works.

http://jsfiddle.net/kbwood/sV4bY/

If you load the bootstrap library additional to the popbox libraries

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

it will not work anymore.

Here is a not working example. Remove the bootstrap.min.css file to make it work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
  <title>PopBox</title>
  <link href="../static/css/popbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <h1>PopBox</h1>

 <div class='popbox'>
   <a class='open' href='#'>
     <img src='' style='width:14px;position:relative;'> Click Here!
   </a>

   <div class='collapse'>
     <div class='box'>
       <div class='arrow'></div>
       <div class='arrow-border'></div>

       Content from first popup
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>  

</div>
</body>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../static/js/popbox.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.popbox').popbox();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: The problem may be occurring  because of  .open css in bootstrap

Comment: It looks like the conflict is in `collapse`; if I change the divs to `collapse2` it works (but the popup positioning is off).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the `collapse` class you have applied to the `div`. In Bootstrap, these are hidden by default as it's part of the accordion feature. Either remove the class from that div or use a different name for it.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tpjjsqg6/

Comment: From the popbox css: `.collapse { position:relative; }`  What an absolutely horrid class name for what it actually does.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Indeed, quite strange - especially as its not used anywhere else in either the CSS or JS file.